# Selenide how to not reuse browser for the next tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenide

I have parameterized test with 8 cases. I run them in parallel with 4 threads, so 4 tests are started at the same time and 4 after. My tests are also doing login to the tested system.
So the problem is that Selenide uses the same browser after test is completed. First 4 tests are passed, but 4 other are failed, because I still logged in and after my login page is opened - I am being redirected to main page.

Is there any option to enable selenide to use new fresh browser session after test ?

I tried manually closing Selenide browser with `WebDriverRunner.closeWebDriver()` after each test. But it seems to me the wrong approach

My test is the following:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"value1", "value2", ... , "value8"})
void demo(String message) {
    open("http://localhost:8080/login", LoginPage.class)
                .loginAsDefaultUser()
                .isMessageDisplayed(message);
}
```

Comment: I don't use Selenide but good testing practices are that for each test you open a fresh browser, complete the test, and quit the browser. Make sure you are doing that for each test. We can't really help much more than that without some sample code for a test and other relevant code from your framework.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. However Selenide does what you said from the box by default. I just want to know if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution provided by Selenide maintainer is to add `closeWebDriver()` method after each test or to use `BrowserPerTestStrategyExtension.class`, which does the same